# Comparing two datatables and separating values from it in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, compare

I'm creating an ASP.net application, in which I have two datatables `dt1` and `dt2`.

Both `dt1` and `dt2` have only 1 column in them as the data. But there rows are different. Some values of `dt1` are the same in the rows of `dt2`. Also `dt2` has extra row values which `dt1` does not have. I need to separate the rows from `dt2` which are not in `dt1` and add it to a new datatable `dt3`.

Suppose `dt1` has 3 values `16, 17, 20` in its single column. And `dt2` has 4 values `15,18,20,22`. I need to separate the values which are in `dt2` and not in `dt1`. For instance in the above example there is only `15,18,22` which are in `dt2` and not in `dt1`. The separated values are then to be stored into a new datatable.

How to do this? Is there any compare function in c# for comparing values in datatables? I'm new to ASP.net. Please help me out..

Comment: You're creating a new application yet you're using data tables?  Is there a reason you can't move to something a little less heavy and a little cleaner?  An IDataReader pattern that maps to objects makes it far easier to compare values in custom .Equals() overrides

Comment: By the looks, this is homework.  But, here is a place to start:  Google "how to compare two datatables values in c#" and you will find the solution to your problem and how to achieve it.